# How to download the audio content of a webpage in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

In Python, I have a list of links, which I want to fetch and download. These are small audios. I am using `selenium` to navigate the website (Chrome) and `requests` to get and download the list of links. The `.status_quote` is 200 for all links. However, all my .wav files are empty, **with 0 bytes**.

How do I fix this?

```
attempt = 0 
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
#**list** previously defined with links from audio files
for item in list:   
  link = list[0]
  name = list[1]
  s = requests.Session()
  s.headers = {'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36')}

  c = [s.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value']) for c in cookies]
  r = s.get(link)
  if r.status_code == 200:
    if len(r.content) > 1:
      with open(os.path.join('audios', name+'.wav'), 'wb') as file:
        file.write(r.content)
      print("Download complete")
  else:
    print("Size is 0 bytes")
```

here's an image from what I can see when accessing one link. Im able to manually download it (3 dots --> download)
[image from audio link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG1bZ.png)

Comment: There are a few improvements to make but it is not immediately clear why this fails. Can you use the Chrome inspector to find the request that downloads the .wav and "Copy as curl" (perhaps in the right click menu) and then use https://ryan.govost.es/http-translator/?

Comment: by doing that, I can see on requests.post(), the headers={}, and data={}. But when the downloads of audio links (from list) are supposedly running, nothing comes up on the Network Chrome inspect tab. Why could this be?

Comment: You mean when you start the download manually in Chrome, it doesn't show up in the inspector, independently from your script?

Comment: @rgov If I download manually it does show on the Network Chrome inspector, with Type "media" and a non-zero size. The output as Python requests (http translator) shows me params{} and headers{} inside requests.get(). I copied that to my script. But again, the downloaded .wav file is 0 bytes. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you run the `curl` command from Chrome directly in the Terminal, does it output anything? (You may to add an `-o xyzzy.wav` flag added to save to disk.)

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. how can I run the `curl` command directly in Terminal? do you mean $ curl https:// (the link I wish to download audio from)? This does not give any output

Comment: In the Inspector's Network tab, find the request you want. Right click on it, go to Copy -> Copy as cURL. Go to Terminal and paste it in and run it. The command makes the exact same request that your browser did. `man curl` explains it.

Comment: thanks. I tried that but no output from Terminal. Also, on Chrome Network: Status =200, Type=media, size=60kB, but I can't download the audio on my program. I am able to manually click on the Download button (see image on updated post above), but when inspecting Elements, it only has <video, <source src = ..., type=audio/wav", <video>. Any thoughts appreciated